# Invoke AppSync from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

According to [this Amplify doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/graphql-from-lambda/q/platform/js/#iam-authorization) before my lambda can query AppSync I need to do 2x things.

1. Assign the correct IAM Roles
2. Sign the request

Why is this necessary - shouldn't the IAM Role be enough to authorize my lambda?

My AppSync's default authorization mode is API, followed by cognito and IAM - should i chamge this?

[image: diagram]

[This blog](https://graphql-on-aws-appsync-book.com/aws-appsync/api-configuration/authorization-providers/#iam) also says I need to sign the request.

A little guide would be appreciated as I'm inexperienced with AppSync :)

Answer (score 0):

AppSync offers 4 authentication methods:

- Amazon Cognito user pools allow your GraphQL API to use user
  attributes for fine-grained access control and filtering.
- API tokens have a limited lifetime and are appropriate for automated
  systems, such as Continuous Integration systems and integration with
  external APIs.
- AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) is appropriate for internal
  applications managed in your AWS account.
- OpenID Connect allows you to control and federate access with the
  OpenID Connect protocol.

In your case, the guides you have referenced are providing the steps for querying AppSync using IAM. Granting the lambda the appropriate role allows it to be able to query IAM and generate the signature to be included in the request. You may be familiar with SDKs which automatically sign requests using a provided role. In the examples you provided above, the lambda function is making an HTTP request to the AppSync endpoint and thus must include the signature which is generated based on the role assigned to the lambda. If this signature was not included or the role did not contain the required permissions, the request would be denied.

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/best-practices.html
https://arpadt.com/articles/signing-requests-with-aws-sdk